# the が in 目が抉られるような痛み

Tags: nuances, passive-voice

目**が**抉られるような痛み

how would it change if i changed it to を? what the difference in nuance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is more grammatical than semantic.

In 目が抉られる, the subject is 目 whereas, in 目を抉られる, the subject is the person whose eye is scooped out. So they literally correspond to

- 目が抉られるような痛み：a pain like an eye being scooped out.
- 目を抉られるような痛み；a pain like having an eye scooped out.